# Listview for ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>with multiple Button for each Item row

Tags: android

I'm a bit new to android, but I am trying to come up with a list view from ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> with button, likes and comments for a chat app[I have been able to create a custom listview for each item as displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pn4Iw.png)

My question is on how to get the update button in my custom listview for each item to be clickable in order to add comments and also maybe how to create a dialog to show comments that exist when clicked.

Please help me for I have been stuck on how to do so for over one week

my code for fragment that holds the list view

```
   public class MinetCommunityInMinetCommunityFragment extends Fragment {
    private SessionHandler session;

    static final String TAG = MinetCommunityInMinetCommunityFragment.class.getSimpleName();

    private ListView lvChat;
    private static final String KEY_EMPTY = "";

    private static final int PICK_PHOTO = 1958;
    private static final int REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE = 1;
    private static String[] PERMISSIONS_STORAGE = {
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
    };

    private static final String KEY_ID_MINET_COMMUNITY = "idminetcommunity";
    private static final String KEY_CONTENTS = "Contents";
    private static final String KEY_DATE_POSTED = "DatePosted";
    private static final String KEY_ADDED_BY = "AddedBy";
    private static final String KEY_POST_TYPE = "PostType";
    private static final String KEY_POST_ID = "PostID";

    private static final String KEY_FIRST_NAME = "F_Name";
    private static final String KEY_LAST_NAME = "L_Name";

    private ProgressBar spinnerAllChats;

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> allChatsList;
    private TextView noDataChats;

    private EditText etMessage;
    private Button btSend;
    private Button btnAttachMinetCommunityImage;
    private TextView tvImageName;
    private ImageView imageViewMinetCommunity;

    private String filePath;

    private String stringContents;
    private String stringImageName;

    private Button btnUpdateChat;

    //for deleting later// TEST PURPOSES
    @Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)
    public void onEvent(EventModel event) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        if (event.isTagMatchWith("response")) {
            String responseMessage = "Response from Server:\n" + event.getMessage();
            //responseTextView.setText(responseMessage);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_minet_community_in_minet_community_fragment, container, false);
        session = new SessionHandler(getActivity().getApplicationContext());

        //HttpsTrustManager.allowMINETSSL();
        etMessage = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.etMessage);
        btSend = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btSend);
        btnAttachMinetCommunityImage = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnAttachMinetCommunityImage);
        tvImageName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvImageName);
        imageViewMinetCommunity = view.findViewById(R.id.imageViewMinetCommunity);
        lvChat = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.lvChat);

        allChatsList = new ArrayList<>();
        verifyStoragePermissions(getActivity());

        noDataChats = view.findViewById(R.id.MinetCommunityNoData);

        spinnerAllChats =(ProgressBar)view.findViewById(R.id.progressBarMinetCommunity);
        spinnerAllChats.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        new GetAllChats().execute();

        btnAttachMinetCommunityImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent = new   Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_PHOTO);

            }
        });

        btSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (validateInputs()) {
                    uploadButtonClicked();

                    Handler handler = new Handler();
                    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            // Do something after 5s = 5000ms
                            allChatsList.clear(); // clear the list view
                            // Update list view
                            new GetAllChats().execute();
                        }
                    }, 2000);
                }
            }
        });

        return view;
    }



    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK ){
            if(requestCode == PICK_PHOTO ) {
                Uri imageUri = data.getData();
                filePath = getPath(imageUri);
                imageViewMinetCommunity.setImageURI(imageUri);
                //imageView.setImageURI(imageUri);
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), filePath, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                tvImageName.setText(filePath);
                // uploadButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            }

        }
    }

    private String getPath(Uri uri) {
        String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = getActivity().managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
        int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(column_index);
    }

    public void uploadButtonClicked() {
        User user = session.getUserDetails();
        String pricipal = user.getUserId();
        stringContents = etMessage.getText().toString();
        stringImageName = tvImageName.getText().toString();

        if(stringImageName.equals(KEY_EMPTY)) {

            String type = "addCommunityComment";

            BackGroundWorker backGroundWorker = new BackGroundWorker(getActivity());
            backGroundWorker.execute(type,pricipal,stringContents);

            etMessage.getText().clear();
        } else {
            NetworkCall.fileUpload(filePath, new ImageSenderInfo( pricipal,stringContents));

            etMessage.getText().clear();
            tvImageName.setText(" ");//filepath
            imageViewMinetCommunity.setImageURI(null);
        }
    }


    private class GetAllChats extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        User user = session.getUserDetails();
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Json Data is downloading",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

            HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();

            //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), user.getUserId(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            String url = "http://10.0.2.2/WellnessMinet/viewMinetCommunity.php";
            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url);

            Log.e(TAG, "Response from url: " + jsonStr);
            if(allChatsList.isEmpty()) {
                if (jsonStr != null) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                        // Getting JSON Array node
                        JSONArray upload_files = jsonObj.getJSONArray("minetcommunity");

                        // looping through All Contacts
                        for (int i = 0; i < upload_files.length(); i++) {

                            JSONObject c = upload_files.getJSONObject(i);

                            // String policy_id = c.getString("");
                            String ID = c.getString(KEY_ID_MINET_COMMUNITY);
                            String contents = c.getString(KEY_CONTENTS);
                            String datePosted = c.getString(KEY_DATE_POSTED);
                            String addedBy = c.getString(KEY_ADDED_BY);
                            String postType = c.getString(KEY_POST_TYPE);

                            String firstName = c.getString(KEY_FIRST_NAME);
                            String lastName = c.getString(KEY_LAST_NAME);


                            // tmp hash map for single upload_file
                            HashMap<String, String> upload_file = new HashMap<>();

                            // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                            upload_file.put(KEY_ID_MINET_COMMUNITY,  ID);
                            upload_file.put(KEY_CONTENTS, contents);
                            upload_file.put(KEY_DATE_POSTED, datePosted);
                            upload_file.put(KEY_ADDED_BY, addedBy);
                            upload_file.put(KEY_POST_TYPE, postType);

                            upload_file.put(KEY_FIRST_NAME, firstName);
                            upload_file.put(KEY_LAST_NAME, lastName);


                            if (c.getString(KEY_POST_TYPE).equalsIgnoreCase("Posts")) {
                                allChatsList.add(upload_file);
                            }
                        }
                    } catch (final JSONException e) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
                        requireActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                                        "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage(),
                                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        });

                    }

                } else {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't get json from server.");
                    requireActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Couldn't get json from server. Check LogCat for possible errors!",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), user.getUserId(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            if (getActivity() != null) {
                // Code goes here.

                    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), allChatsList,
                            R.layout.list_chats, new String[]{KEY_DATE_POSTED, KEY_CONTENTS, KEY_FIRST_NAME, KEY_LAST_NAME},
                            new int[]{
                                    R.id.PostDateChat,
                                    R.id.tvPostChat,
                                    R.id.tvFnameChat,
                                    R.id.tvLnameChat
                            });
                    lvChat.setAdapter(adapter);

            }

            //set height to see all items - hack because of listview in scrollable view
            Utility.setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(lvChat);
            //ListUtils.setDynamicHeight(lvChat);
            if (allChatsList.isEmpty()){
                noDataChats.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            spinnerAllChats.setVisibility(View.GONE);


            lvChat.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "this row clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    btnUpdateChat = view.findViewById(R.id.btnUpdateChat);
                    btnUpdateChat.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {

                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "this row clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });

                }
            });

        }
    }

    public static class Utility {
        public static void setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(ListView listView) {
            ListAdapter listAdapter = listView.getAdapter();
            if (listAdapter == null) {
                // pre-condition
                return;
            }

            int totalHeight = 0;
            int desiredWidth = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(listView.getWidth(), View.MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
            for (int i = 0; i < listAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
                View listItem = listAdapter.getView(i, null, listView);
                listItem.measure(desiredWidth, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
                totalHeight += listItem.getMeasuredHeight();
            }
            //I added this to try to fix half hidden row
            totalHeight++;

            ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listView.getLayoutParams();
            params.height = totalHeight + (listView.getDividerHeight() * (listAdapter.getCount() - 1));
            listView.setLayoutParams(params);
            listView.requestLayout();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Checks if the app has permission to write to device storage
     *
     * If the app does not has permission then the user will be prompted to grant permissions
     */
    public static void verifyStoragePermissions(Activity activity) {
        // Check if we have write permission
        int permission = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

        if (permission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // We don't have permission so prompt the user
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                    activity,
                    PERMISSIONS_STORAGE,
                    REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
            );
        }
    }

    /**
     * Validates inputs and shows error if any
     * @return
     */
    private boolean validateInputs() {

        if (KEY_EMPTY.equals(stringContents)) {
            etMessage.setError("Message post cannot be empty");
            etMessage.requestFocus();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }


}
```

Code for the custom Listview for each listview Item

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TableRow android:padding="5dp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                        android:id="@+id/profile_image_chat"
                        android:layout_width="96dp"
                        android:layout_height="74dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:contentDescription="@string/nav_header_desc"
                        android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
                        android:src="@drawable/profile"
                        app:civ_border_color="#DAD8D8"
                        app:civ_border_width="2dp" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="300dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:orientation="horizontal">

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/tvFnameChat"
                                android:padding="1dp"
                                android:textSize="16dp"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:textStyle="bold"
                                android:textColor="#03A9F4"/>

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/tvLnameChat"
                                android:padding="1dp"
                                android:textSize="14dp"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:textStyle="bold"
                                android:textColor="#03A9F4"/>

                        </LinearLayout>

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/PostDateChat"
                            android:textSize="10sp"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:textStyle="bold"
                            android:textColor="#9E9A94"/>

                    </LinearLayout>

                </TableRow>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvPostChat"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageViewChat"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/profile" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:weightSum="4"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/idDeleteChat"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="2"
                        android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_delete"
                        android:padding="10dp"
                        android:text="Delete"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:visibility="invisible"/>
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tvLikesChat"
                        android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_thumb_up"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:layout_weight="2"
                        android:padding="10dp"
                        android:text="Like (0)"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_weight="2"
                        android:padding="10dp"
                        android:layout_width="50dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tvCommentsByCommunityChat"
                        android:text="Comments (1)"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_insert_comment"
                        android:layout_weight="2"
                        android:padding="10dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/backborder"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/etResponseChat"
                        android:layout_width="290dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:padding="10dp"
                        android:hint="Response"
                        android:background="@drawable/backborder"/>
                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btnUpdateChat"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@drawable/buttonrectanglegreenchat"
                        android:text="Update"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        android:textAllCaps="false"/>

                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

        </TableLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate "CLEARLY" your question?
Couldn't understand what you want to convey.

Comment: I want a button click listener for each row of the list view. I hope that is more clear.Thank you

Comment: can you add your code?

Comment: Is necessary to see your code, but if you need a listener for each row, really you need a listener in the row list: yourRow.setOnClickListener {  } and inside of brackets you need to know what button is, for example with a button type and use a switch case statement to do the right action

Comment: Manuel Mato....I have posted the code. And since I don't know the definite future size that the list view will hold, can I have a switch case for indefinite listview content?